# Refreshing a custom linestring layer in MapBox GL JS on Geocoder event

Tags: ajax, mapbox-gl-js

I am working with MapBox GL JS and want to redraw a linestring layer based on a Geocoder.on event.

I have the following by way of code and what I am finding is that my linestring draws on the first .on event but nothing happens on subsequent events. Not really sure what I am missing here. I have validated that my Ajax call is returning the desired data point but can't quite figure how to update my linestring layer.

```
map.on('load', function() {
        // Listen for the `result` event from the Geocoder
        // `result` event is triggered when a user makes a selection
        //  Add a linestring based on an Ajax call to a Django model
        geocoder.on('result', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'map',
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    longitude: e.result.geometry.coordinates[0],
                    latitude: e.result.geometry.coordinates[1]
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    map.addSource('linestring_layer', {
                        type: 'geojson',
                        data: {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            properties: {},
                            geometry: {
                                'type': 'LineString',
                                'coordinates': response.linestring
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    map.addLayer({
                        id: 'linestring_layer',
                        type: 'line',
                        source: 'linestring_layer',
                        layout: {
                            'line-join': 'round',
                            'line-cap': 'round'
                        },
                        paint: {
                            'line-color': '#00FF00',
                            'line-width': 4
                        }
                    });
                    map.getSource('linestring_layer').setData({
                        type: 'Feature',
                        properties: {},
                        geometry: {
                            'type': 'LineString',
                            'coordinates': response.linestring
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, the second time your event triggers, `map.addSource()` throws an exception because that source has already been defined, and the rest of the handler is skipped.

You should add your source and layer once, outside the handler. And only call `setData()` within the handler.

Comment: You were spot on, moving the addSource() outside of my event and then calling the setData() on event did the trick. Thanks a lot!